# org-clock-report: Add line and calculate average working hours

Tags: org-mode, org-table, org-clock-table

I am using `org-clock-report` to keep track of my daily working hours. Example:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 2
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-07-26 Mi 06:04]
|   Headline |     Time |
|------------+----------|
| *Total time* | *2d 13:23* |
|------------+----------|
| 18.07.2023 |     8:40 |
| 19.07.2023 |     8:41 |
| 20.07.2023 |     7:22 |
| 21.07.2023 |     8:35 |
| 24.07.2023 |    11:24 |
| 25.07.2023 |     8:02 |
| 26.07.2023 |     8:39 |
#+END:
```

How can I add a line with the average daily working hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the setup you have makes it marginally more complicated. For the sake of providing you with at least a partial answer, which may spur someone to provide a more complete one, here is something that works easily if you use the `subtree` scope.

The main reason why the subtree scope is convenient, here, is that it provides a third column, which means I have an existing empty cell in which I can put information.

The key is to change the clocktable properties to add a formula

`#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope subtree :maxlevel 2 :formula "@2$3=vmean(@4$3..@>$3);U"`

This will add the mean of the hours into the empty cell next to the total time for the subtree. Here's a small example:

```
* clock
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope subtree :maxlevel 2 :formula "@2$3=vmean(@4$3..@>$3);U"
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2023-07-26 Wed 13:42]
| Headline           | Time    |       |
|--------------------+---------+-------|
| *Total time*       | *21:00* | 05:15 |
|--------------------+---------+-------|
| clock?             | 21:00   |       |
| \_  Time           |         |  6:00 |
| \_  Only time      |         |  2:00 |
| \_  Can bring back |         |  4:00 |
| \_  Our love again |         |  9:00 |
#+TBLFM: @2$3=vmean(@4$3..@>$3);U
#+END:

** Time
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-07-26 Wed 12:41]--[2023-07-26 Wed 18:41] =>  6:00
:END:
** Only time
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-06-26 Wed 12:41]--[2023-06-26 Wed 14:41] =>  2:00
:END:

** Can bring back 
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-05-26 Wed 12:41]--[2023-05-26 Wed 16:41] =>  4:00
:END:
** Our love again
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2023-04-26 Wed 12:41]--[2023-04-26 Wed 21:41] =>  9:00
:END:
```

The references I used to figure this out are primarily under https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Spreadsheet.html - it's not particularly pretty, but it is incredibly powerful. You'll find things in here like the `U` for time calculations and the meanings of `$` and `@` and `@>`.

I am not entirely sure how to *add a new table line* after the fact through the `org-clock-report` function.

This being said, you may be able to leverage the above to write a function that first calls `org-clock-report` and then modifies the resulting table, now that you have a sense of the formula you need to use to get the average.

I hope this helps - I know it's not a complete answer to your question.

Comment: +1 for the `;U` which I think I knew at one point but had certainly forgotten. But I too don't know how to add an empty row at the end of the table, other than using a `:formatter` function - but that would mean basically copying and modifying `org-clocktable-write-default` - or maybe it could be done by advising the function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Because of your answer I learned 1) how to add spreadsheet formulas to `org-clock-report` functions and 2) learned about `;U`. As the total hours are not important to me, I am replacing it now by the average; so your answer really solved my problem! `#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 2 :formula "@2$2=vmean(@3$2..@>>$2);U::@2$1=Average time"`